# Difference between arima.predict() and arima.forecast()

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, arima

What is difference between `arima.predict()` and `arima.forecast()`.

Which function should use for **forecasting time series** in python?

Comment: Are you referring to the `statsmodels` implementation? Please clarify, since that implementation does not include a `forecast` method ([docs](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_model.ARIMA.html)).

Answer (score 1):

They will give you the same answers. But the combination of Arima (not arima) and forecast from the forecast package are enhanced versions with additional functionality.

Arima calls stats::arima for the estimation, but stores more information in the returned object. It also allows some additional model functionality such as including a drift term in a model with a unit root.

forecast calls stats::predict to generate the forecasts. It will automatically handle the drift term from Arima. It returns a forecast object (rather than a simple list) which is useful for plotting, displaying, summarizing and analysing the results.

Comment: Hello! Could you provide some extra information like sources or something in which you base you answer?

Comment: It seems you are referring to the respective R functions & packages, while OP asks about Python stuff...

Comment: This is the exact same answer as in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223872/forecasting-arima-with-predict-vs-forecast-in-r, which was specifically based on the R-environment.